# ios - Switch from Normal AR View to Headset AR View

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

There's any way to switch from **Normal View** to **Headset View** and keep all models inside last view.
I'm working with placing models on the ground in **Normal View**, then user clicks a button to switch to **Headset View** (and wear google cardboard).
I want to keep all models which user placed them on the ground after switching view.

Switch from Normal AR View

[image]

To Headset AR View
[image]

> Preference:
>   https://github.com/hanleyweng/iOS-ARKit-Headset-View/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this before but not this exact thing, but this might work.

The way that I would do this would be by creating only one `ARSCNView` that is always running, and then when switching to headset view create two `SCNViews` with the same `scene` property as the `ARSCNView` and with the same `pointOfView`

I haven't tested this, but it should work.